# How do I test this rails 3 controller function with rspec 2 using factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot

Using Rails 3, Rspec 2, factory_girl_rails gem, I have a controller with the following code:

```
def remove_player
 @player = User.find(params[:id])
 current_team.users.delete(@player)
 current_team.games.each do |g| 
   ug = GamesUser.where(:game_id => g.id, :user_id => @player.id)
   ug.each {|x| x.destroy}
 end
 redirect_to(team_path(current_team), :notice => 'Player was successfully removed from this team')
end
```

It works fine and does what I need it to do. However, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong in my tests which look like this:

```
    describe "Remove player" do
    before do
        @team = Factory(:team)
        @player = Factory(:user)
        @game = Factory(:game)
        controller.stub!(:current_team).and_return(@team)
    end

    it "should remove player from team" do
        @team.users << @player
        @team.users.should have(1).users
        post :remove_player, :id => @player.id
        @team.users.should have(0).users
    end

    it "should remove games from player schedule" do
        Factory(:games_user, :user_id => @player.id)
        @player.should have(1).games
        post :remove_player, :id => @player.id
        @player.should have(0).games    
    end
end
```

The first test passes. However the second one does not. I am new to rspec and testing in general, so feel free to point out any flaws that you see - I won't be offended.

The gist of what I am trying to do here is remove a player from a team (Team has_many Users) and remove any games from that player's schedule (Game habtm Users through GamesUser). Oh and "current_team" is a helper method that fetches a Team based on a session variable.

Comment: The main flaw I see is the presence of controller specs. :) IMHO RSpec is great for models, but RSpec controller specs are painful -- use Cucumber instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully compare your assertions, you are calling the :has_many 'users' on "@team" in the first case,

```
@team.users.should have(0).users
```

but **not** calling the :has_many 'games' on the "@player"

```
@player.should have(0).games
```

Without looking at the documentation (I might be wrong) I think the "games" in `have(1).games` is just syntactic sugar. Please verify and let me know.